# How to use iOS OSLog with Xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nslog

How can I use the iOS [OSLog](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/oslog) in Xamarin.iOS?

I did succeed in using NSLog as follows, but I see no way of setting the subsystem (to the bundle identifier) with NSLog so that I can use that to filter the logs in Console.app.

```
public class Logger
{
    #if DEBUG
    [DllImport(ObjCRuntime.Constants.FoundationLibrary)]
    private extern static void NSLog(IntPtr message);
    #endif

    public void WriteLine(string line)
    {
        #if DEBUG
        using (var nss = new NSString(line))
        {
            NSLog(nss.Handle);
        }
        #endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In `Xamarin.iOS`, there is a static `CoreFoundation.OSLog` object called `Default` that one can use straight away which will log messages with the specified `OSLogLevel` argument such as `OSLogLevel.Debug`, `OSLogLevel.Error` etc. 
You could have a method in your `Xamarin.iOS` code that logs a message at the `Debug` level:

```
using CoreFoundation;
// ...

public void Write(string message)
{
    OSLog.Default.Log(OSLogLevel.Debug, message);
}
```

If you want to use the subsystem and category, you have to instantiate an instance of `OSLog` using the appropriate constructor and use that instance to log your messages. Presumably you'd want to hold a static reference to your created instance and use it like you'd use `OSLog.Default`.

```
public partial class AppDelegate : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public static OSLog LoggerInstance;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        LoggerInstance = new OSLog(subsystem: "subsystem", category: "category");
//...

public class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        AppDelegate.LoggerInstance?.Log(OSLogLevel.Debug, "log message");
        // ...
    }
```

This will print a fairly nice message in the device log with a timestamp and showing the specified category.

Answer (score 3):

`OSLog` is a ObjC struct (of two const chars) and a kernel method, `os_log_create`, is provided to allocate one.

Note: Refer to the `os/log.h` for details.

#### Define:

```
[DllImport("__Internal", EntryPoint = "os_log_create")]
public static extern IntPtr os_log_create(string subsystem, string category);
```

#### Usage:

```
var oslog = os_log_create("some.bundle.id", "StackOverflowCategory");
```

FYI: your NSLog should include a printf format string as a NSString

```
[DllImport (Constants.FoundationLibrary, EntryPoint = "NSLog")]
extern static void NSLog (IntPtr format, [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string s);
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I use the oslog variable to produce debug output?

Comment: @Harindaka You linked to the OSLog class/object (which is a Swift framework wrapper for `os_log_t`) so that is what I answered on. If you what to use the unified logging system and pass a `os_log_t` to it, I would recommend looking at `os/log.h`. `_os_log_impl` is the base method for unified logging (`_os_log_internal` is deprecated) and you can marshal its parameters from C# to ObjC. Again you should review os/log.h as most of it is just macros that wrap `os_log_type_enabled` and the low level `_os_log_impl` call.

Comment: Sorry I'm not much of a swift/objc dev. I will have a look at that. I can see from this link (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/227392) that there is a method  which has the following signature: os_log_with_type(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, OS_LOG_TYPE_DEFAULT, "Hello os_log!"). Is this the same as the oslog variable above and if how can I import the consts OS_LOG_DEFAULT and OS_LOG_TYPE_DEFAULT or OS_LOG_TYPE_DEBUG/OS_LOG_TYPE_INFO, etc

Comment: I actually want to output debug messages

Comment: @Harindaka `os_log_with_type` is a just macro for `os_log_type_enabled` and `_os_log_impl` (this is defined in `os/log.h`)  For a `os_log_type` of just `OS_LOG_TYPE_DEBUG` you can just use  `Console.Writeline` But if you want control over the category, the bundle sub ids, etc... then `_os_log_impl` is the call you want as it is the kernel call that the ObjC macros and the Swift framework is using.

Comment: @SushiHangover you mean `_os_log_internal`, I assume?